# Accessing root files on Ubuntu Phone from my eOS based on Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, filesystems

I am wondering if it is possible to access the root files on my Ubuntu Phone E5 from my computer. I know I can access them from the terminal on the phone but it is not ideal using that touchscreen to explore. Is there a way to gain access to these files from my ElementaryOS (Freya, based on the Ubuntu distro)?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here but haven't played around with it.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/538129/ubuntu-touch-remote-access-to-device